# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 on Mac when using Qt+opencv+ffmpeg

Tags: macos, qt, opencv, gcc, ffmpeg

I'm running a project using Qt+opencv+ffmpeg on Mac, but it comes to an error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64.

---

Part of .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil
```

---

When I use GCC (x86 64bit in /usr/bin) to compile, it shows

```
error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

When I use Clang (x86 64bit in /usr/bin) to compile, it shows

```
error: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

I'm using OS X Yosemite 10.10.4. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: You have to add necessary `opencv` libraries to your `LIBS` flags.

Comment: Can you include the list of symbols that weren't found? For ffmpeg linking flags, use "pkgconfig --libs libavformat libavcodec libavutil", not -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have included the path with `INCLUDEPATH`but not the library itselfs with `LIBS`

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881913/how-to-link-opencv-in-qtcreator-and-use-qt-library) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067538/adding-opencv-library-to-qt-creator-and-getting-error-linker-command-failed-wit) answer helps you:

Comment: I tried the second this, and now it works, thank you so much!